# Google Calendar Event GoogleAuthIOException

Tags: android, authentication, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create a new `Event` in Google Calendar.  I also refered to the `Calendar` sample App for creating an `Event` and it's working fine if I create a new `Calenda`r but when I tried to create a new `Event` it is showing `GoogleAuthIOExcepion`.

Here is My Code:

```
public class CSA extends ActionBarActivity 
{
    Button createEventBtn ;
    Event createdEvent ;
    GoogleAccountCredential credential;
    com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this,
            Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR));

    client = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
            transport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName(
            "CreateEventTestApp ").build();

    createEventBtn = findViewById(R.id.button);
    createEventBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new MyTask(client).execute();
        }
    });

}

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Event> 
{

    com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar services;

    public MyTask(com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar service) 
    {
        Log.v("Loading....", "Loading..." );

        this.services = service;
    }

    @Override
    protected Event doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        Log.d("Service Event created", "Service Event created");

        Event event = new Event();

        event.setSummary("summary");
        event.setLocation("place");

        ArrayList<EventAttendee> attendees = new ArrayList<EventAttendee>();
        attendees.add(new EventAttendee().setEmail("email");
        event.setAttendees(attendees);

        Date startDate = new Date();
        Date endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + 3600000);
        DateTime start = new DateTime(startDate,
                TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));       
        event.setStart(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(start));

        DateTime end = new DateTime(endDate, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        event.setEnd(new EventDateTime().setDateTime(end));


        try {       
            createdEvent = client.events().insert("primary", event).execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
        return createdEvent;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Event result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }

 }

}
```

and the error it is showing is :

> 05-09 15:55:32.816: W/System.err(19365): com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthIOException
>
> 05-09 15:55:32.937: W/System.err(19365):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:286)
>
> 05-09 15:55:32.937: W/System.err(19365):  at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
>
> 05-09 15:55:32.937: W/System.err(19365):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
>
> 05-09 15:55:32.937: W/System.err(19365):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
>
> 05-09 15:55:32.941: W/System.err(19365):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
>
> 05-09 15:55:32.941: W/System.err(19365):  at com.example.csa.csa$MyTask.doInBackground(CalendarSampleActivity.java:371)
>
> 05-09 15:55:32.941: W/System.err(19365):  at com.example.csa.csa$MyTask.doInBackground(CalendarSampleActivity.java:1)
>
> 05-09 15:55:32.941: W/System.err(19365):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>
> 05-09 15:55:32.945: W/System.err(19365):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
>
> 05-09 15:55:32.945: W/System.err(19365):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
>
> 05-09 15:55:32.949: W/System.err(19365):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>
> 05-09 15:55:32.949: W/System.err(19365):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
>
> 05-09 15:55:32.953: W/System.err(19365):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
>
> 05-09 15:55:32.953: W/System.err(19365):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>
> 05-09 15:55:32.957: W/System.err(19365): Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: BadUsername
>
> 05-09 15:55:33.109: W/System.err(19365):  at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
>
> 05-09 15:55:33.109: W/System.err(19365):  at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
>
> 05-09 15:55:33.113: W/System.err(19365):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:255)
>
> 05-09 15:55:33.113: W/System.err(19365):  at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:279)
>
> 05-09 15:55:33.113: W/System.err(19365):  ... 13 more

Please help if anyone already tried this.

Comment: @ayushi did you get solution of this issue? because i am also facing this one from last one week.

Comment: Hello Have u tried adding the google auth key to your manifest file

Comment: ohk checked it now. :)